# How to segue UIImage from camera to another view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, image-capture

I'm trying to capture a photo using a camera button and pass that image through a segue to another view controller for editing. There is something wrong with my code because when I press the camera button the app crashes. Here is the code for the camera view controller. I've checked all connections in the storyboard.

```
@IBAction func snapStillImage(sender: AnyObject) {

    print("snapStillImage")
    dispatch_async(self.sessionQueue, {
        // Update the orientation on the still image output video connection before capturing.

        let videoOrientation =  (self.previewView.layer as! AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer).connection.videoOrientation

        self.stillImageOutput!.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo).videoOrientation = videoOrientation

        // Flash set to Auto for Still Capture
        View3.setFlashMode(AVCaptureFlashMode.Auto, device: self.videoDeviceInput!.device)



        self.stillImageOutput!.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(self.stillImageOutput!.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo), completionHandler: {
            (imageDataSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, error: NSError!) in

            if error == nil {
                let data:NSData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(imageDataSampleBuffer)
                let mainpictures:UIImage = UIImage( data: data)!
                                    let orientation: ALAssetOrientation = ALAssetOrientation(rawValue: mainpictures.imageOrientation.rawValue)!



                func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

                    if (segue.identifier == "test") {

                        let destViewController : photoEditViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! photoEditViewController


                        destViewController.mainpictures = "edit"
```

Here is the code for the second view controller

```
class photoEditViewController: UIViewController {


var mainpictures = String ()


@IBOutlet var mainImage: UIImageView!



override func viewDidLoad() {


    if let image = UIImage(named: mainpictures) {
        self.mainImage.image = image
    }
```

Thanks community

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, provide the error message that you get, when the app crashes.

Comment: so on my camera view controller the error message is

Comment: Value of type 'photoEditViewController' has no member 'mainpictures'

Comment: You need to look at some samples online. There are a lot of technical things that appear to be off in this code. What is your error? I would not expect this to run at all. Are you really wrapping a prepareForSegue function in a dispatch async call??  That is not going to work. A simple search of "UIImagePickerController tutorial" will give you lots of examples from which you can [start](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=uiimagepickercontroller%20tutorial)

Comment: And on my destination view controller it reads    cannot assign value of type 'UIImage!.Type' (aka 'ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<UIImage>.Type') to type 'UIImage?'